how to add icon tag inside of a textinput
Here I created a div class under the div class add a img tag which is work for showing the profile pic. After that we can see a <TextInput> with some css. Outside of this <TextInput/> have a custom button which is work for submit the post basically.
I want to move this <IoMdSend/> inside of the text input. When i put that tag inside of text input it shows error or sometimes it did not show the icon in frontend, it might go under the text input..
how to add that icon  here...
<div className="w-full flex items-center justify-between gap-2 py-4 border-b border-[#66666645]">
                <img
                  src={user?.profileUrl ?? NoProfile}
                  alt="User Image"
                  className="w-14 h-14 rounded-full object-cover"
                />
                <TextInput
                  styles="w-full rounded-full py-5 px-4 pr-12 position: relative" // Add position: relative for child elements
                  placeholder="What's on your mind...."
                  name="description"
                  register={register("description", {
                    required: "Write something about post",
                  })}
                  error={errors.description ? errors.description.message : ""}
                >
                </TextInput>
                {/* <IoMdSend
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "2.2rem",
                    color: "#ccc",
                  }}
                /> */}
                {posting ? (
                  <Loading />
                ) : (
                  <CustomButton
                    type="submit"
                    title="Post"
                    containerStyles="bg-[#0444a4] text-white py-1 px-4 rounded-full font-semibold      text-sm"
                  />
                )}
              </div>

>


Can you add images supporting your question ? This kind of lacks the clarity on what you are trying to achieve in here.

you can use react fragment for this. If you want to render two divs, a React Fragment must be used first
If the code inside the TextInput looks like this it won't work:
<div className="text-input">
.. todo something
</div>
<IoMdSend
  style={{
   fontSize: "2.2rem",
   color: "#ccc",
  }}
/>

If you change the code like this it will work
<>
 <div className="text-input">
  .. todo something
 </div>
 <IoMdSend
  style={{
   fontSize: "2.2rem",
   color: "#ccc",
  }}
 />
</>

